# What governs DC scaling?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gdi, wmf

This code gets different scaling depending on which computer I run it on.

```
        Metafile image;
        IntPtr dib;
        var memoryHdc = Win32Utils.CreateMemoryHdc(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 1, out dib);
        try
        {
            image = new Metafile(memoryHdc, EmfType.EmfOnly);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                Render(g, html, left, top, maxWidth, cssData, stylesheetLoad, imageLoad);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Win32Utils.ReleaseMemoryHdc(memoryHdc, dib);
        }
```

Going into the Render method, the Metafile object has a PixelFormat of DontCare and consequently does not have valid vertical or horizontal resolutions.

Coming out of the Render method, it has a value of `Format32bppRgb` and `PhysicalDimension.Width` and `PhysicalDimension.Height` have increased to accommodate the rendered image.

**How can I make scaling independent of local settings?**

Here's the implementation of `CreateMemoryHdc` (I didn't write it, it's from an OSS library).

```
    public static IntPtr CreateMemoryHdc(IntPtr hdc, int width, int height, out IntPtr dib)
    {
        // Create a memory DC so we can work off-screen
        IntPtr memoryHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SetBkMode(memoryHdc, 1);

        // Create a device-independent bitmap and select it into our DC
        var info = new BitMapInfo();
        info.biSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        info.biWidth = width;
        info.biHeight = -height;
        info.biPlanes = 1;
        info.biBitCount = 32;
        info.biCompression = 0; // BI_RGB
        IntPtr ppvBits;
        dib = CreateDIBSection(hdc, ref info, 0, out ppvBits, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        SelectObject(memoryHdc, dib);

        return memoryHdc;
    }
```

As you can see, the width, height and bit depth passed to the DC constructor are constant. Creating the metafile produces different physical dimensions. Right after executing this

```
            image = new Metafile(memoryHdc, EmfType.EmfOnly);
```

the metafile has `PhysicalDimension.Height` (and width) of 26.43 on my workstation and 31.25 on the server to which I am deploying, so the difference in scaling is already evident and therefore probably not a consequence of anything in the rendering.

This may be relevant. `BitMapInfo` is defined in the OSS library and looks like this:

```
internal struct BitMapInfo
{
    public int biSize;
    public int biWidth;
    public int biHeight;
    public short biPlanes;
    public short biBitCount;
    public int biCompression;
    public int biSizeImage;
    public int biXPelsPerMeter;
    public int biYPelsPerMeter;
    public int biClrUsed;
    public int biClrImportant;
    public byte bmiColors_rgbBlue;
    public byte bmiColors_rgbGreen;
    public byte bmiColors_rgbRed;
    public byte bmiColors_rgbReserved;
}
```

so possibly setting `biXPelsPerMeter` and `biYPelsPerMeter` will help. The above code *doesn't* set them and may be allowing platform values.

Unfortunately, setting these values doesn't seem to make any difference. msdn says

> **biXPelsPerMeter**
>
> The horizontal resolution, in pixels-per-meter, of the
>   target device for the bitmap. An application can use this value to
>   select a bitmap from a resource group that best matches the
>   characteristics of the current device.

So these settings are used when *loading* a bitmap *from a resource*. No help here.

This all looks pertinent https://www.codeproject.com/articles/177394/%2fArticles%2f177394%2fWorking-with-Metafile-Images-in-NET

It may help to know that this code does not run in an application. It renders HTML as a metafile for printing, and it lives inside a Web API webservice.

There is no user interface so I'm not sure how to interpret the question of whether it is DPI Aware. The evidence suggests it's DPI *affected* so the question may be pertinent.

Comment: Is your application DPI aware? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI doesn't scale. Use GDI+ for device independence. You will lose antialiasing but most print devices are high DPI anyway.

Does the library in use have an option to use GDI+ instead?

(In my own case, yes. Problem solved.)